# Spring 3 samples

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Could you recommend me some web portals or sites, where I can find good examples (or tutorials, screencasts) for the third version of Spring?

P.S. I'm beginner in Spring (and in java web-frameworks). And now I'm choosing the version of Spring to learn (between 2.5 and 3). Which one would be best for me?

Answer (score 3):

[Spring 3 Framework Reference Manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/)

[Spring 3 Sample Apllications](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/)

> Which one would be best for me?

Latest version is [3.0.5.RELEASE](http://www.springsource.org/download), learn it.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-example/spring-example.html
I hope this will help you....before u go through this u must know some basics about spring here i give one sample program first u understand the spring flow.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
class computer {
private String keyBoard;

public void setKeyBoard(String keyBoard) {
    this.keyBoard = keyBoard;
}
public String getKeyBoard() {
    return keyBoard;
    }
}
public class A {
public static void main(String...args) {
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("computer.xml")); 
    computer comp = (computer)factory.getBean("keyboard");
    System.out.println(comp.getKeyBoard());
    }
}
```

context.xml

```
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="keyboard" class="computer">
<property name="keyBoard" value="Dell"/>
</bean>
```

batch file to execute the program

```
cls
set CLASSPATH=.;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\commons-logging.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.asm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.aspects-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.context.support-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.instrument-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.jms-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.orm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.oxm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.test-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.transaction-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;E:\SpringPrograms\lib\org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar;

javac A.java

java A
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample!